# Change default behavior of data-filter in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have an unordered list with `data-filter="true"` attribute.
How can I hide the list items while the filter box is empty?
Should I override the default list view behavior? how?

This is actually a work around in order to filter a collapsible-set with UL in each collapsible block. What I want to do finally is to display data-filter with hidden content, and the collapsible set, so if the user choose to use the filter, the collapsible set should be hidden, and only filtered result will be shown.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is no way to override the default behavior of jquery mobile for this. you need to add your handling on top of the jquery mobile code. try the following:

For this, you will need to define your stylesheet as follows:

```
  .ui-hidden-component {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

And add the following script code:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', 
      function() { 
        var $listview = $(this).find('[data-role="listview"][data-filter="true"]'); 
        $(this).delegate('input[data-type="search"]', 'keyup change', 
          function () { 
            var $this = $(this); 
            if ($this.val() == '') {
              $listview.children().addClass("ui-hidden-component");
            } else {
              $listview.children().removeClass("ui-hidden-component");
            }
          });
        if ($('input[data-type="search"]').val() == '') {
          $listview.children().addClass("ui-hidden-component");
        }
    });
```